# Requirejs random script error (chromium)

Tags: google-chrome, ckeditor, requirejs

We are having problems with requirejs as it randomly fails to load files--see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v326D.png). In Chrome the network tab says that it failed to load, but it does not provide a proper http response code--see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYder.png). On refresh everything could be working fine again.

This resource (ckeditor) is shimed by `"lib/ckeditor/ckeditor": {
            exports: "CKEDITOR"
        }` and we are using requirejs v2.1.6.

Anyone else having problems like this?

Comment: Can you provide more of your require.config? Do you use baseUrl?

Comment: Yes we use baseUrl, it is defined as: `/assets/js/app`. Furthermore we have 
    `paths: {
        lib: '../lib',
        view: '../../view',
       'jquery': '../lib/jquery'
    }`

and some shim definitions:

    `"lib/bootstrap": {
        deps: ["jquery"],
        exports: "$.fn.popover"
    },
    "lib/jquery.nestable": ["jquery"],
    "lib/bootstrap-modalmanager": ["jquery", "lib/bootstrap"],
    etc...`